# Can I develop Android watch app to run without mobile phone?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am planning a new application that I would like to put on the smartwatch. I would like to have it usable also when there is no phone nearby. The app needs no Internet connection to work, could synchronize data to the phone later and I do not need anything from the phone while the app is running. However I could use the phone no problem to install the app.

I have googled, there are some foggy talks on a web that this is not possible, Android watch must always be connected to the phone for apps to run. How much is it true?

Comment: I didn't try to create watch app yet. I think you can run app which is not communicating with phone app but you cannot submit watch app to Google play

Comment: No problem to install it from Google play through the phone. I only want it to be independent later.

Answer (score 2):

With Android Wear 2.0 it is possible to now develop standalone applications and thus eliminates the need for a mobile 'companion' completely. 
Please follow this link for more information: https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/index.html

As I am aware, the current Android Wear version **always** requires a companion app for installation purposes etc. But with 2.0 this is no longer necessary. It would probably make sense for you to start developing with 2.0 now. That being said, it is still in a development preview and can officially run on only two smart watches (Huawei Watch and LG Watch Urbane 2nd Edition)

Answer (score 1):

Wearable apps are run directly on wearables and don't require presence of a phone except for installation or phone-provided features (voice recognition, SMS, internet connection etc.)

Note that some features are wearable-provided or phone-provided depending on the hardware configuration of the watch/wearable (eg. GPS).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is most definitely possible. As long as the wearable app doesn't require any functionality from the phone then it can operate as a standalone device. It will require a companion app on the phone to [install](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html) the app on the wear device.

There are several wear apps that work without the need to be tethered to the phone, including Google Play music. There is the possibility of designing wear apps for hardware on only a few wear devices - I know that [Ghostracer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bravetheskies.ghostracer&hl=en_GB) has standalone functionality using GPS, but it requires the wear device to have a GPS chip (it is designed for the Sony SmartWatch 3).